# GCC/clang compile error with function-scoped static pointer to unnamed array

Tags: c, gcc, scope, static, clang

Why do GCC and clang show "error: initializer element is not constant" and "error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant" (respectively) when defining a function-scoped `static` pointer initialized to an unnamed array; but, when defining the same static pointer to the same unnamed array in file-scope they manage just fine.

I have compiled the same program using a compiler for embedded H/W, which compiles without error.

Here is a code snippet with the error active:

```c
int foo()
{
    static int *ptr = (int[]) { 9, 8, 7 }; /* COMPILE ERROR */
    return ptr[2];
}

int main(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

And here is a similar code snippet with the `static` pointer in file scope, which GCC and clang compile without issue:

```c
static int *ptr = (int[]) { 9, 8, 7 }; /* File-scope is fine */

int foo()
{
    return ptr[2];
}

int main(void)
{
    return foo();
}
```

I can of course define a separate static array inside my function and point my static pointer to that array, but I want to use an unnamed array. I have tried different compiler flags to no avail:

- `-std=c90`
- `-std=c99`
- `-std=c11`
- `-std=gnu11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the scope of the compound literal (i.e. your "unnamed array"); when that is used at **file scope** (as in your second snippet), then the C Standard specifies that it has *static* storage duration, so it can be used as an initializer.

However, a compound literal declared at **block scope** (as in your first example) has *automatic* storage duration, so it's address cannot be used as an initializer in this context.

From [this Draft C11 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.5.2.5 Compound literals
>
> …
> 5     The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object
> initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs
> outside the body of a function, the object has static storage
> duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
> the enclosing block.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the rigorous answer!